# Raspberry PI impossible to refresh automatically chromium

Tags: raspberry-pi, chromium, autostart

At work we gave me a raspberry pi with an existing autostart chromium to a website.
So when we boot the raspberry it does automatically start chromium and shows the right website.
The only problem we have now is that the raspberry sometimes lost his connection to internet and so it get a `404 page not found`.
From this point because we can't reach the website we also get stuck on `404 error` infinitly.
I have access to the website but of course if I code something on the html page which is not reachable it won't be executed. I've heard javascript could still be active if my raspberry lose connection but I really doubt about this...

I would like to refresh 5minute after we get a 404 error message. And if we still can't reach it then retry 5minutes later again etc...

The simple way to do this is to download a chrome plugin autorefresh.
But almost all the chrome plugin to autorefresh are not compatible and the one who are compatible are not enabling on the startup of chromium.

I saw multiple solutions on the internet like making a `cron -e` task to simulate a `F5` push, but I'm not a fan of this since when I take control of the computer I will have to deal with  `F5` automatically called.

If anyone has an optimal way to do this it would be great.

Thanks.